# How to calculate total area of all features of a class in ArcGIS without double counting overlaps

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, area, overlapping-features

I have a polygon feature class with a field "Area" in the Attribute Table calculating the area of each features. Some features overlap each other. How can I calculate the total area of all the features without double counting the overlaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have an advance level license (by the way when you ask questions always include version/license) then you can do the following:

1. Run the Union tool using the layer by itself.
2. Run delete identical based upon shape field.

Comment: Simply dissolve?

Comment: @FelixIP yeah that would work! I guess I am over thinking things. :) Time for a beer...

Comment: Thanks. Both workded. And didn't know "delete identical" tool. very useful

Comment: @cartographer67 Please accept the answer so that it can help others.